# ./configure invalid option "-user=nginx"

Tags: nginx, rtmp, centos6

I am a complete newbie to centos and I am trying to install nginx with the rtmp module following the tutorial here: http://www.notehub.org/2014/1/21/compiling-nginxnginx-rtmp-module-on-cent

Everything works fine till I try to run the ./configure command where i get the following error:
./configure: error: invalid option "-user=nginx"

Please tell me what I am doing wrong and how do I do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that his blog auto-changed `--` to a long dash `–`. if you search and replace that long-dash with two -- then it configures just fine.